# AngularJS Leaflet Markers Won't Render

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, marker, angular-leaflet-directive, ionic-view

I've been trying to implement a marker and path trail to a leaflet map inside an ionic project and have been using following this angularJS with Leaflet documentation/example found [here](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/path). However, when implementing I cannot get the pins to be visible. Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garrettmacmac/49xVW/28/). I also included some of my code because it wouldn't let me submit my question without but its the same rendering issue on my JSFiddle. Any help would be great!

I'm being forced to show code if I have a JSFiddle link, so this is what I got but I don't think the solutions in my code. If some library or call issue.

my **index.html**

```
<style>
.scroll { height: 100%; }
map {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
  .angular-leaflet-map {
  display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffff;
  }
</style>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

my **pathmap.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Activities" >
<ion-content ng-controller="PathController" class="has-header">

 <leaflet center="center" paths="paths" defaults="defaults"></leaflet>

 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controller.js**

```
    angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic', 'leaflet-directive', 'ngCordova'])

[......]


.controller("PathController", [ '$scope', function($scope) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            center: {
             lat: 25.074521,
            lng: -77.348191,
            zoom: 14
            },
            paths: {
                p1: {
                    color: '#33CCCC',
                    weight: 3,
                    latlngs: [
                        { lat: 25.074521, lng: -77.348191 },
                        { lat: 25.074501, lng: -77.317485 },
                        { lat: 25.081517, lng: -77.319116 },
                        { lat: 25.078077, lng: -77.345831 }


                    ],
                }
            },
            markers: {
                marker1: {
                    lat: 25.074521,
                    lng: -77.348191,
                    icon: {
                        url: 'img/nirvana.jpg',
                        iconSize: [80, 80],
                        iconAnchor: [40, 80],
                        popupAnchor: [0, 0],
                        shadowSize: [0, 0],
                        shadowAnchor: [0, 0]
                    }
                },
                marker2: {
                    lat: 25.074501,
                    lng: -77.317485,
                    icon: {
                        iconUrl: 'img/logo.png',
                        iconSize: [800, 800],
                        iconAnchor: [400, 600],
                        popupAnchor: [40, 40],

                    }
                },
                marker3: {
                    lat: 25.081517,
                    lng: -77.319116,
                    icon: {
                        iconUrl: 'img/logo.png',
                        iconSize: [800, 800],
                        iconAnchor: [400, 600],
                        popupAnchor: [40, 40],

                    }
                },
                marker4: {
                    lat: 25.078077,
                    lng: -77.345831,
                    icon: {
                        iconUrl: 'img/logo.png',
                        iconSize: [800, 800],
                        iconAnchor: [400, 600],
                        popupAnchor: [40, 40],

                    }
                },


            },
            defaults: {
                scrollWheelZoom: false
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have `markers="markers"` and needed to update my `leaflet.js` Hope this helps someone else out.

> Without `markers="markers"` and old leaflet.js
>
> [image]

---

> With `markers="markers"` and updated leaflet.js
>
> [image]

Comment: This is what @Okyne said.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call markers in your leaflet directive.

```
<leaflet center="center" paths="paths" defaults="defaults" markers="markers"></leaflet>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This fixed the issue for the JSfiddle, however, not my project. I'm not sure what is causing it, I'm thinking it could be a library call, however if I find it I will update here. or if anyone knows of what would have cause this please let me know. Thanks.